# $setPristine() does not work properly if form control has invalid data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to reset form using $setPristine().

```
$scope.resetDataEntryForm = function() {
    $scope.dataEntryForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.pr = {};
};
```

It works fine if all the input controls in valid state. one of the input type is URL. For example, if i have invalid URL value at the time i click reset. should the above code reset the contents of URL input field and mark error to false. I need this for validations.

To do the proper reset i have to manually reset all error flags

```
$scope.resetDataEntryForm = function() {
    $('#dataEntryForm')[0].reset();
    $scope.dataEntryForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.dataEntryForm.name.$error.required = true;
    $scope.dataEntryForm.site.$error.required = true;
    $scope.dataEntryForm.site.$error.url = false;
    $scope.pr = {};
};
```

Can anybody please suggest proper way to reset form using angular.js ?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: Seems like $setPristine is broken since it leaves $error in it's current state. This doesn't fix it but is a little more appropriate than the assignments you are using: `$scope.dataEntryForm.site.$setValidity("url", false);`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it intended or not, but `$setPristine()` does not change `$error` object.

This is the source code for setPristine on Form

```
    form.$setPristine = function () {
        element.removeClass(DIRTY_CLASS).addClass(PRISTINE_CLASS);
        form.$dirty = false;
        form.$pristine = true;
        forEach(controls, function(control) {
          control.$setPristine();
        });
      };
```

and this is the code call on Control (input element etc)

```
    this.$setPristine = function () {
      this.$dirty = false;
      this.$pristine = true;
      $element.removeClass(DIRTY_CLASS).addClass(PRISTINE_CLASS);
    };
```

Seems to me that you will have to reset `$error` object yourself

PS: The code is taken from AngularJs version 1.2.*, you can check the current version on Github https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/291d7c467fba51a9cb89cbeee62202d51fe64b09/src/ng/directive/form.js